# Is it a bad idea to have multiple smoke domains?

Tags: rendering, performance, mantaflow

I have this scene with 3 smoke domains, each with different properties. Whenever I try to render in cycles, it crashes. I'd like to know if using multiple smoke domains is significantly more demanding compared to using a single large domain.

Comment: Just to try it I placed 1 vs 3 vs 8 domain with low res render to make quick comparison, you can render multiple domain but it is quite growing in demand...
1 domain 1.33 seconds... 3 domains 3.44 seconds ... 8 intersecting domains 7.45 seconds... so yes it pretty much multiplies it for me, 1 domain 1 second = 8 domains cca 8 seconds

Comment: thanks for the help, i'll try to avoid it then

Comment: This question might suffer the fate of being closed because as the title is articulated now, it's asking for opinion-based answers. I didn't vote to close since as @MikoCG points out it makes a difference, which might be useful information. However, and this is why it's opinion-based, it strongly depends on what you want to achieve and what you are willing to compromise. If I want to mix different smoke and fire elements because some settings give better results than others for different parts, then sometimes it might be better to mix multiple domains - if your machine can handle it.